# contar con count php lista con 2 parametros

Tags: php, mysqli

```
Tengo la siguiente funcion que me cuenta los tickets donde los tipo de solicitud sean iguales a 2 o a 5.


function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion){

            $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud  AND (status ='2' or status ='5' )")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
            $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
            return $resultados[0];

        }
```

[image: cuenta de los tickets en la base de datos]

Lo que quiero implementar es una cuenta pero solo de los tickets que sean relacionados id_departamento del usuario.

Intento hacerlo con la siguiente funcion agregándole el parametro id obtenido en la búsqueda.

```
function cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion, $id){

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                                     FROM ticket as t
                                     JOIN usuario AS u
                                     ON t.id_usuario = u.id
                                     WHERE t.status <> '3' AND u.id_departamento = ".$id."") 
                                     or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
```

[image: error]

Pero tengo el siguiente error ...
Cual seria el error?

Gracias .

Muestro el resultado asi

```
  <?php 

 $resultados = $ticket->cuentaticketspendienteempleado($conexion,$id);

 if($resultados > 0) // validamos si es mayor a 0
{
    echo '<div id="notificacion">',$resultados,'</div> '; 

}else{

echo 'GG';
 } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Con qué comparas `tipo_solicitud`....? `.. WHERE tipo_solicitud  = ???? AND ...` Si la escribes por ejemplo así debería funcionar: **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud =1  AND status ='1' `**

Comment: no lo comparo con nada @A.Cedano , me traigo todos los campos que tengan algo en tipo de solicitud porque no importa si es 1 ,2,3 ... 
lo que importa es que me traigan la cuenta de los tickets que sean igual al id del que esta usando el sistema, el u.id_departamento sea = ".$id."

Comment: Entonces no entiendo ¿por qué tienes `tipo_solicitud` en el `WHERE`? Sería entonces así: `SELECT COUNT(*) conteo FROM ticket t JOIN usuario u ON t.id_usuario = u.id WHERE t.status = '1'  AND u.id_departamento = $id` ...

Comment: me da error @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Qué error da Juan?

Comment: ¿Tú necesitas contar solamente cuántas filas hay, o necesitas otras columnas aparte del conteo?

Comment: @A.Cedano buen dia, no tenia internet . solo las filas pero que sean  u.id_departamento = ".$id."

Comment: O sea, ¿tú quieres saber únicamente cuántas filas cumplen con el criterio `u.id_departamento = ".$id.` ?, no te interesan ningún otro dato más. Espero que me aclares eso para proponerte una solución.

Comment: si , solo para empezar . luego de que pueda ver como hacerlo le añadire lo del status @A.Cedano

Comment: Lo del status también se puede añadir. Yo me refiero a las columnas del `SELECT ...` ¿qué columnas necesitas ahí?  El problema es que una respuesta adecuada necesitará del uso de consultas preparadas y se requiere saber cuántas columnas entrarían en el `SELECT` y cómo se llaman esas columnas.

Comment: se debe seleccionar todo 
SELECT *
contar todas las filas de la tabla ticket 
donde el status sea <> '3' y el 
id del departamento del usuarios sea igual a el mismo

Comment: Un `SELECT *  ` con MySQLi  y consultas preparadas (que sería lo correcto aquí) requeriría de usar una función suplementaria. El problema es que mysqli no permite el uso de métodos como `fetch_row` en esos casos, a no ser que tengas un driver suplementario instalado. Podría darte una solución basada en esa función suplementaria, o bien basada en PDO, que es una herramienta como `mysqli`, pero mejor. Tú me dirás.

Comment: @A.Cedano voy a editar la pregunta para que veas mejor cual es el error que tengo

Answer (score 0):

```
function listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $id){

    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, COUNT(t.id) as contador_tickets, t.id as id_ticket, u.id as user_id, t.fecha_creacion as t_fcreacion, t.hora_creacion as t_hcreacion
                                         FROM ticket as t
                                         JOIN usuario AS u
                                         ON t.id_usuario = u.id
                                         WHERE t.status <> '3' AND u.id_departamento = ".$id." ORDER BY t.id DESC ") 
                                         or die("Error listando Ticket: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    return $consulta;
}
```

Sólo incluye el COUNT en tu misma función.

Comment: you have an error in your SQL syntax ; check the manual thant corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right suntax to use near 'ORDER BY t.id DESC' at line 5 @alberto Siurob

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el error @alberto siurob

Comment: Bueno, el error es de un ; no tiene nada que ver con la query. Revisa tu consulta o haz un echo de la misma, creo que $id está vacío.

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta para ser mas claro @Alberto

Comment: Aver quitale el quitale el ORDER BY t.id DESC